# Laravel - get only 1 line by creation

Tags: php, html, database, laravel, web

I'm learning with laravel and I'm stuck on one thing, I have a table with id (Auto Increment) then I have levy (int), our_balance (int), created_at (timestamp) and updated_at (timestamp) there, I always need to only the last line gotten and from it I need our_balance to read it from the new calculation. So I need to get the data from the line that was created last.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your table name is 'accounts' and it has a model named 'Account'

Note: to get the last inserted data or row.

```
$lastRecord = Account::latest()->first();
```

or

```
$lastRecord = Account::orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();
```

Then to get the our_balance field data

```
$ourBalance = $lastRecord->our_balance;
```

or

```
$ourBalance = $lastRecord['our_balance'];
```

i hope that answers your question